# How to limit the amount of characters shown for an HTML string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, tags

I am trying to find a way to show a part of an HTML string in PHP. For example, the string is something like this.

```
<p align="center">Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur <u>adipiscing elit</u>. Vestibulum nec augue ut elit semper sagittis. Etiam consectetur odio id urna condimentum, ultrices porttitor quam dapibus. Cras tincidunt ex gravida, bibendum nulla quis, egestas urna. Praesent mattis, ante et lobortis porttitor, risus est fermentum purus, at pretium sapien turpis vitae tellus. Maecenas lacinia condimentum urna eget vestibulum. Cras sodales, purus sit amet luctus consequat, tortor dolor viverra nibh, ut feugiat ante sem ac justo. Suspendisse potenti. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras eu ornare tortor. Mauris accumsan, ex sit amet luctus posuere, velit neque ultricies orci, faucibus faucibus elit elit vitae massa. Nulla tempus molestie est id facilisis. Sed dignissim efficitur orci, ut accumsan magna pellentesque a. Sed tempor fringilla arcu sed porttitor.</p>
```

As you can see above, the string includes some HTML elements. I want to show the first 60 characters of the string which means that I want to show something like this:

```
<p align="center">Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur <u>adipiscing elit</u>. Ves</p>
```

The HTML tags are not taken into consideration during the characters counting and also the paragraph tag should be closed. Has anyone achieved something like this?

Comment: Have you tried something till yet?

Comment: Take a look at `substr()` I think you can get what you want with a loop

Comment: @SuperDJ `substr` will not be helpful in skipping `HTML` tags.

Comment: @SahilGulati you could do an extra check on the last few characters but that would make it quite complicated yes.

Comment: Regex is the best solution. Any character between `̀<p align="center">` and `</p>` And a limit on the number of character.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one will be helpful.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/850260)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string ='<p align="center">Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur <u>adipiscing elit</u>. Vestibulum nec augue ut elit semper sagittis. Etiam consectetur odio id urna condimentum, ultrices porttitor quam dapibus. Cras tincidunt ex gravida, bibendum nulla quis, egestas urna. Praesent mattis, ante et lobortis porttitor, risus est fermentum purus, at pretium sapien turpis vitae tellus. Maecenas lacinia condimentum urna eget vestibulum. Cras sodales, purus sit amet luctus consequat, tortor dolor viverra nibh, ut feugiat ante sem ac justo. Suspendisse potenti. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras eu ornare tortor. Mauris accumsan, ex sit amet luctus posuere, velit neque ultricies orci, faucibus faucibus elit elit vitae massa. Nulla tempus molestie est id facilisis. Sed dignissim efficitur orci, ut accumsan magna pellentesque a. Sed tempor fringilla arcu sed porttitor.</p>';
$resultString="";
$counter=0;
while(!empty($string[0]))
{
    if(preg_match("/^<\/?[a-z]+\s*.*?>/",$string,$matches))
    {
        $resultString.=$matches[0];
        $strlen=strlen($matches[0]);
        $string=substr_replace($string, "",0,$strlen);
    }
    elseif($counter<60)
    {
        $resultString.=$string[0];
        $string=substr_replace($string, "",0,1);
        $counter++;
    }
    elseif($counter>=60)
    {
        $string=substr_replace($string, "",0,1);
    }
}
echo $resultString;
```